# Sublime tab size only working for some files

Tags: ide, sublimetext3

Im using Sublime Text 3 for a javascript app. When I tab, I want it converted to 4 sapces. So I have set:

```
"tab_size": 4,

"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,
```

This works fine. But weirdly, on some files (that also have .js extension like the ones it works on), a tab still only translates to 2 spaces. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All settings in Sublime Text follow an [Order of Precedence](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/extensibility/packages.html#merging-and-order-of-precedence). Here's an hypothetical example for JavaScript (in ascending order):

- Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
- Packages/Default/Preferences (Windows).sublime-settings
- Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
- Packages/JavaScript/JavaScript.sublime-settings
- **Packages/User/JavaScript.sublime-settings**

In this case, the bold settings will override all the others. In your case, a JavaScript package might override your user preferences.

What you can do is define `tab_size` in `Preferences > Settings - Syntax Specific`. Make sure you're current view is a JavaScript file before opening the setting.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had to set `"detect_indentation": false`, **and then close and reopen the file**. When you leave the file opened, it will "remember" the indentation even across Sublime restarts.

Comment: Thanks ! Though it didn't work when I wrote it in my `.sublime-project` file, I had to write it in the global preferences (`Preferences.sublime-settings`)